# Send mail error send-mail: message from server : 504 5.5.2 <-c>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address

Tags: linux, smtp, sendmail, msmtp

I want to send an email to various recipients with command line.
I'm using the stmp server from my email providers and msmtp is the smtp client (on linux).
The command I use is:

```
mail -s 'mysubject bla bla' dest1@free.fr -c dest2@club-internet.fr <<< 'Hello'
```

and I have the error message:

```
send-mail: l'adresse de destinataire -c n'est pas acceptée par le serveur
send-mail: message du serveur : 504 5.5.2 <-c>: Recipient address rejected: need fully-qualified address
send-mail: le courriel n'a pas pu être envoyé (compte default dans /home/user/.msmtprc)
```

Here is my .msmtprc config:

```
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
logfile        ~/.msmtp.log

account myaccount
host smtp.free.fr
port 465
from myaccount@free.fr
user myaccount@free.fr
password xxxxxxx
tls_starttls off
tls_certcheck on

# Set a default account
account default : myaccount
```

It works fine if I don't specify -b or -c recipient, but if I add one of these, I have the error message.
I tried with several recipient email addresses on different domains and it's the same.
Thanks

Comment: The syntax for mail seems to be `mail [-dEIinv] [-a header] [-b bcc-addr] [-c cc-addr] [-r from-addr] [-s subject] [--] to-addr ...`